# Rest the memory of python from script

Tags: python

I am running a script that needs a lot of memory...
I can use `reset` to clear all variables so I will have memory clear for a second run...
However my question is how can I enter this `reset` in a loop so after every run it will clear the memory by itself.

Thanks appreciated

Comment: reset: resets all variables from command line

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.. it's maybe a command in your shell (!= python shell), and it doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: looks like an ipython magic function

Comment: My recommendation below. Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a script requiring lots of memory, I would recommend running that in a separate process (which gets cleaned automatically). You can do this either by:

- using some other script to launch the workers (e.g. `bash`)
- using python [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) to launch the worker processes

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting [MemoryError](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.MemoryError) exceptions, you might consider rewriting your script to write to a database or a file instead of holding all of your data in memory. Some good options for this are [MySQL](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python), [Redis](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis/), and [Mongo](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymongo/2.2.1), among many, many others.

Of course, it may also be possible to avoid all of this database stuff entirely if you can find places in your code where memory is being used inefficiently or unnecessarily. If you post your code, I'm sure folks will be happy to take a peek!

As an example, if you have large [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) holding lots of data that is being processed one item at a time, you can probably get pretty good memory savings by switching to a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Python interpreter utilizes garbage collection to free memory of unused objects. Normally, this process doesn't require any manual correction. However, you can collect garbage earlier than it is scheduled using *gc* module. http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html

This will free some memory for your script.